# FFMPEG restricting keyframes

Tags: ffmpeg, keyframe

Hey all this command works fine for me while extracting keyframes : ffmpeg -vf select="eq(pict_type\,PICT_TYPE_I)" -i yourvideo.mp4 -vsync 2 -s 160x90 -f image2 thumbnails-%02d.jpeg.

I was just wondering if someone knows what will work with this to restrict the number of keyframes to say,200. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `-vframes 200` as an output option.